# json parsing using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have trouble in parsing the JSON using the Javascript.My resultant variable 'text' do does not have the result after completion of loop. Can anybody guide me how can I parse this JSON properly.

```
var xmlr = null;
var text = '';
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlr.readyState == 4 && xmlr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlr.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
            text += '<option>' + data[i].member_first_name + '</option>';
        }
        console.log(text); // here not get result in text
    }
}
xmlr.open("GET", "data.json", true);
xmlr.send();
```

also content of data.json are

```
[
{"member_id":"3","member_first_name":"sachin ","member_last_name":"kumar"},
{"member_id":"4","member_first_name":"abhijit","member_last_name":"kumar"},
{"member_id":"5","member_first_name":"nithin","member_last_name":"ev"},
{"member_id":"6","member_first_name":"tukaram","member_last_name":"kumar"},
{"member_id":"7","member_first_name":"manish","member_last_name":"mungle"},
{"member_id":"8","member_first_name":"dsfdgfh","member_last_name":"dfgfhgfh"},
{"member_id":"9","member_first_name":"hjhgjkhkhj","member_last_name":""},
{"member_id":"10","member_first_name":"hjhkjhggf","member_last_name":""},
{"member_id":"11","member_first_name":"klkjlgfhf","member_last_name":"hjghkj"},
{"member_id":"12","member_first_name":"jkhkjhkl","member_last_name":"hgjgffhfkhj"},
{"member_id":"13","member_first_name":"hfgtjgjhg","member_last_name":"fghjgfhjg"},
{"member_id":"14","member_first_name":"hgjgfjhj","member_last_name":"hgjhgjhfg"},
{"member_id":"15","member_first_name":"cvcxvnvnbv","member_last_name":"nbvcbvc"},
{"member_id":"16","member_first_name":"vbvcnbnbm","member_last_name":"vbxgdssdg"},
{"member_id":"17","member_first_name":"lkfndbfbsd","member_last_name":"dfggfhfh"},
{"member_id":"18","member_first_name":"fghjjdfd","member_last_name":"fgfghghf"},
{"member_id":"19","member_first_name":"ghgfjhfj","member_last_name":"fghfhfd"},
{"member_id":"20","member_first_name":"dfhgfhh","member_last_name":"gdfhfd"}
]
```

Comment: You should use Jquery for that, it's much easyier. What does the data variable contain? i'm guessing you're looping over the wrong part of your json object.

Comment: @DominikGoltermann No he should not. it's pure js  and I think the problem is that json is undefined

Comment: If you have an array, why not just use Array.map?

Comment: well you should showw the JSON. @DominikGoltermann why jquery, its easy in js also

Comment: I guess your script won't ever reach the console.log` make another "break" points.

Comment: Your code itself looks fine. The problem is most likely down to the response format. Insert `console.log(data)` before the `for` loop, run your code, and post the console output in your question so we can see what the response looks like.

Comment: @meda, Roy Namir because that code above is not cross browser compatible.

Comment: @DominikGoltermann the question is about parsing json not about ajax

Comment: i know. but does it do any harm to give him that hint?

Comment: could you show the ouput of `console.log(xmlr.responseText)`

Comment: also can you provide `data` after `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @Lorenzo i do not able to show screenshot of console but **console.log(xmlr.responseText)** shows the content of data.json in string formate and **console.log(data)** after **JSON.parse** content the objects array.

Answer (score 0):

To traverse the object array best available in java script that , traverse the object array using **for/in** loop than for loop, so my final code which traverse the object array as follow:-

```
var xmlr = null;
var text = '';
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlr.readyState == 4 && xmlr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlr.responseText);
        for (var key in data) {
            text += '<option>' + data[key].member_first_name + '</option>';
        }
        console.log(text); 
    }
}
xmlr.open("GET", "data.json", true);
xmlr.send();
```